# Win API to Scroll Up and down the navigation pane in outlook 2010

Tags: winapi, outlook, navigation, vsto, directory

I know that using .net VSTO there is no way to do this. but what my addin is doing : 
When a user clicks on a folder in outlook on the navigation pane, I am showing another folder instead. jus by using the ActiveExpolorer.CurrentFolder = MyNewFolder. the issue here is that outlook will scroll down to the new folder and I want to prevent this.

I can't set back the current folder to the original folder because I am using the FolderSwitch event and so it will be ea endless loop.

I am thinking if I could make it remember the navigation bar position and then set it back to that position when the user click on the folder. using win 32 api ? any ideas ?

or I could reset the current folder to the original folder once the new folder displays it content but then I need to stop outlook displaying the content of the original folder and have no idea how to do this.

Cheers

Meb0134

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to resolve this issue.

Within the FolderSwitch Event, I create a NivigationFolder on the Favorites Pane for the Folder that I want to show (Instead of the folder the user clicks on) and then select the new NavigationFolder (NavigationFolder.Select = True) and then deselect (NavigationFolder.Select = False)  and finally I delete the NavigationFolder from the Favorites pane.

This works perfectly even if the Favorites pane is off.

Mehdi Benkhaldi